# How to see the "Latest Solid Milestone Index" of my neighbors?

Tags: iri-node, milestones, syncing, neighbors

I would like to know if it is possible to see the syncing status of my neighbors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via curl if the neighbor exposes the getNodeInfo API:

```
curl -H 'X-IOTA-API-VERSION: 1.4' \ 
  -d '{"command":"getNodeInfo"}' \ 
  http://<hostname>:14265
```

Comment: Note: this command only works if the neighbor has the API open on the port 14265